# List in java using Random numbers

Tags: java

I am getting the following error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ShufflingListAndArray
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

{
    List services = 


    //Arrays.asList("COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER");

 Arrays.asList(new String[] {"COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER"}); 

   Random rnd=new Random();
  String s = services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));

    Collections.shuffle(services);


    //Collections.sort(list);


    System.out.println("List sorting :"+ services);
  }
}
```

After compiling the above code I get the following error.

```
C:\>javac ShufflingListAndArray.java
ShufflingListAndArray.java:17: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
  String s = services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));
                         ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `List services ...` to `List<String> services`

Answer (score 1):

List.get() returns an Object. You need to cast it or use generics to store it in a String variable.

To use generics:

```
List<String> services = ...
```

To cast it:

```
String s = (String)services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error is pretty clear:

```
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
```

It says that `Object` is returned (found), but that your code requires it to be a `String`.

You need to either parameterize the `List` with help of [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf), so that it will instantly return a `String` on every `List#get()` call (more recommended):

```
List<String> services = Arrays.asList("COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER");
```

**or** to [downcast](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) the returned `Object` to `String` yourself:

```
String s = (String) services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

need to specify it is a list of strings

```
List<String> services = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER"});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350266/list-example-in-java) question, it seems to me that you are using older version of Java than Java 5.

The following code should work with it :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ShufflingListAndArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List services = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"COMPUTER", "DATA", "PRINTER"}); 
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String s = (String) services.get(rnd.nextInt(services.size()));
    Collections.shuffle(services);
    System.out.println("List sorting :" + services);
  }
}
```